# Strategy for upgrading to a binary-incompatible version of Ignite

Tags: devops, ignite, release-management, change-management

I am evaluating Apache Ignite data grid for the production usage.

One of critical requirements is to have a well defined stragegy for upgrading a large system to a binary incompatible version (usually unavoidable when using binary protocols like Ignite does). More specifically, upgrading the Ignite infrastructure independently (before or after) from the large number of Ignite client node components and/or Ignite thin clients.

So wondering what would such process look like, for situation when upgrading all the components of the system as a big-bang is not practically possible.

Comment: Are we talking about migration of all persisted data to a new setup? Or replacing nodes in cluster one-by-one?

Comment: @Denis - first - upgrading versions of clients one at a time (before or after upgrading all the nodes), second - upgrade the existing data. The second is not particularly critical in our usecase as the date is loaded fresh every operation cycle (day, week, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your primary objective is clients which should access cluster without downtime during upgrade, I can recommend that most of those clients should be 'thin' clients, such as JDBC client, ODBC client, REST or Java/C#/C++/node.js thin clients which are under active development currently. They have no strict version checking.

So you should avoid using 'thick' clients (a.k.a. Apache Ignite client nodes) and only for operations which can't be performed by thin clients. Or use Rolling Upgrades as mentioned.

Comment: Say we go for a Thin Java client - would it not have problems of binary incompatibility that the Thick client would? I thought they'd be using the same binary protocol between the cluster nodes and the client.

Comment: @bobah Thin client protocol is expected to be backwards compatible. Intra-cluster protocol which Ignite nodes is too complex so version is checked strictly for it.

Comment: does the fact that intra-cluster protocols have strict version checking mean that the protocol is always incompatible between different Ignite versions?

Comment: @bobah We don't get to know because nodes of different versions of Apache Ignite will not connect to each other. There's GridGain on top of Apache Ignite which has rolling upgrades by making sure there's no incompatible changes.

Comment: the thin client approach seems to be working in most practical cases

Answer (score 2):

First, Ignite cares about the compatibility of its binary format and doesn’t change it without some fallback mechanisms. In particular, backward compatibility of the persistent storage (ability to upgrade and continue to use the same DB files) is preserved.

Second, to upgrade a production cluster there is a Rolling Upgrade feature offered by GridGain (built on top of Ignite). See this for details: https://docs.gridgain.com/docs/rolling-upgrades.

Comment: The primary concern is upgrading the large system one component (Ignite client node or thin client) at a time before or after the Ignite infrastructure itself has been upgraded, not the storage format as such. I have updated the question with this info as well.